# Ubuntu 17.04 connected to WiFi, but can't reach default gateway and no internet until arping

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, internet

Since a few days my Ubuntu 17.04 laptop connects to my WiFi, but I have no Internet and I can't open the router website with the default gateway ip http://192.168.0.1. Everything times out after a while.

I'm using a `Wireless 7260` card from Intel if that matters.

I have deleted the connection from the Network Manager, added it again, tried it with manually setting a DNS and without. `sudo service network-manager restart` doesn't work either.

I also added `wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no` to `NetworkManager.conf` but that didn't help so I removed it again.

I found out that a few seconds after doing a `arping 192.168.0.1 -I wlo1` the Internet works again. If a website in Firefox has been loading unsucessfully for a while, I go to the terminal and do the arpping and 2 - 3 seconds later the website loads and everything else works too.

It worked fine in the past, so I'm confused what it might be. I also noticed it happened once on my Windows 10 computer, but only after sleep or hibernate mode. Disabling and reenabling the network adapter fixed it. It might be that my ISP's router did a stealth firmware upgrade, but I couldn't find any mention of that.

Update: I changed the WiFi channel on my router from manual (channel 48) to automatic and back to manual (channel 48) again. Now it seems to work fine. That's weird because restarting my router didn't help. I'll update again if the error comes back.

Update 2: 12 days later and the bug is back. I attached the output of `route -n` as requested. The output stays the same after an arping.

```
$ route -n
Kernel-IP-Routentabelle
Ziel            Router          Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlo1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlo1
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlo1
```

Comment: What's the output of `route -n` ?

Comment: @LasVegasCoder I added an update with the output.

Comment: do aptitude update && aptitude safe-upgrade -y` that should update and upgrade your system with newer updates which may fix the problem.

Comment: @LasVegasCoder is it okay to use aptitude if I have installed everything else with apt?

Comment: Yes please.  Use `aptitude update && aptitude safe-upgrade -y`

Comment: @LasVegasCoder ok, I just did. Nothing was installed, updated or removed.